# Simplifying luatex expression in ConTeXt

Tags: math-mode, luatex, context

I use lua in ConTeXt as described [here](https://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/cld-mkiv.pdf). I have this code which simply prints `$a x + b = 5$` where `a` and `b` substituted

```
\startitemize[a, columns]
\startluacode
 context.startitem()
   context.startimath()
   context.getvariable("mynamespace", "a")
   context("x + ")
   context.getvariable("mynamespace", "b")
   context("= 5")
   context.stopimath()
 context.stopitem()
\stopluacode
\stopitemize
```

And I try to simplify:

- This does not work because `x` is not printed:

  ```
   context("%s x", context.getvariable("mynamespace", "a"))
  ```
- That neither (it seems I can't assign that):

  ```
   local a = context.getvariable("mynamespace", "a")
   context("%s x ", a)
  ```

Anyone help to simplify the expression?

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to produce exercises on the Lua side, you don't even need TeX macros to store content. This may be a starting point:

```
\starttext
\startluacode

--Let's use a global namespace
--Variables will be accessible in any \startluacode ... \stopluacode block
userdata = userdata or {}
userdata.vars = 
    {
    ["a"] = 7,
    ["b"] = -3,
    ["c"] = -4,
    ["d"] = 3 -- Add more if you need it
    }

--Locals avoid clashes and allow shortcuts
--They are defined only inside \startluacode ... \stopluacode blocks

local vars = userdata.vars

--%i is an integer and %I is a signed integer (it always prints the sign)

local fmt  = string.formatters["%i x %I = 5"] --see cld-mkiv for reference
local ctx  = context

ctx.startitem()
ctx.m(fmt(vars["a"], vars["b"]))
ctx.stopitem()
ctx.startitem()
ctx.m(fmt(vars["c"], vars["d"]))
ctx.stopitem()
\stopluacode
\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From this [official](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/CLD_passing_variables#Variables) documentation, it works:

```
 context.startitem()
   -- Recuperam els paràmetres
   local a = tokens.getters.macro(tokens.getters.macro("??variables") .. "mynamespace"..":".."a")
   local b = tokens.getters.macro(tokens.getters.macro("??variables") .. "mynamespace"..":".."b")
   local c = tokens.getters.macro(tokens.getters.macro("??variables") .. "mynamespace"..":".."c")
   context("$ %s x + %s = %s $", a, b, c)
 context.stopitem()
```

Comment: I don't know if we could simplify the `tokens.getter.macro` part.